# Has this generalization of arithmetic progressions been studied?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-progressions

A subset of $[1, \dots, n]$ is said to be 3-AP (arithmetic progression) free if for all $x_1, x_2, x_3$ we have $x_1 + x_2 \ne 2x_3$.

I am interested in a generalization of this concept: subsets of $[1, \dots, n]$ with the property that for all $x_1, \dots, x_k$ we have $x_1 + \dots + x_k \ne kx_{k+1}$.

Is there a name for this in the literature?  Have basic questions about it been answered -- for example, what is the largest "K-AP free" subset (terrible name, I know) of $[1, \dots, n]$?

Comment: The $3-$AP actually is about an arithmetic progression - if such $x_1,x_2,x_3$ exist, they are in arithmetic progression. Your condition for $k>3$ is not about arithmetic progressions, however. $k$-AP should mean there is no AP of length $k$ in the set.

Comment: Yes -- that's sort of my point.  That's why the literature on $k$-APs is not useful to me, and I"m looking for something more general.